# Why my datatable is only working on function index

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

Hi I have a datatable with ajax inside of it that calls a function to get and show the results inside the controller.

The result of the datatatble looks like this and it's working.[image]

My problem is it only works in index controller with the link of for example.

```
http://localhost/zcaexample/admin/feetype
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {
  $this->load->view('feetype');
}
```

But when you access it in another controller with same view for example

```
public function sample() {
  $this->load->view('feetype');
}
```

with a link of:

```
http://localhost/zcaexample/admin/feetype/sample
```

the datatable will have an error of this.
[image]

**My Jquery:**

```
var manageFeetypeTable; // global variable

$(document).ready(function() {

  manageFeetypeTable = $("#manageFeetypeTable").DataTable({
      'ajax' : 'feetype/fetchFeetypeData',
      'order': []
  });
});
```

**My Controller: It has the results of ajax.**

```
public function fetchFeetypeData()
  $feetypeData = $this->model_feetype->fetchFeetypeData();
  $result = array('data' => array());

  $x = 1;
  foreach ($feetypeData as $key => $value) {

    $button = '<!-- Single button -->
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="text-align:left;" dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="text-align:left;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editFeetypeModal" onclick="editFeetype('.$value['feetype_id'].')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="text-align:left;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeFeetypeModal" onclick="removeFeetype('.$value['feetype_id'].')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Remove</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </div>';

    $result['data'][$key] = array(
      $x,
      $value['feetype_name'],
      $value['feetype_role'],
      $value['feetype_dateadded'],
      $button
    );
    $x++;
  } // /for each

  echo json_encode($result);  
}
```

Can you guys tell me what's wrong or what's the problem?

Comment: Probably because of the relative URL in this DataTables option `'ajax' : 'feetype/fetchFeetypeData'`, use absolute URL instead, for example `/zcaexample/admin/feetype/fetchFeetypeData`.

Comment: I used this and it worked http://localhost/zcaexample/admin/feetype/fetchFeetypeData. Do you know why it worked with relative urls?

Comment: use 'ajax' : "<?php echo base_url('feetype/fetchFeetypeData'); ?>"

Comment: I would correct @GeordyJames statement here. This should be like:
use 'ajax' : "<?php echo base_url('admin/feetype/fetchFeetypeData'); ?>" as Cecatrix wants to hit Admin controller's method.